# Changing /accessing the origin and orientation of point cloud

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

For some testing purposes i would like to edit the origin and orientation of the point cloud (viewpoint) for example to add some gaussian noise (not to change the values in the file but just inside the code). Also assuming that i have loaded the point cloud as below

```
    PointCloudPtr cloud_in (new PointCloud);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile (argv[1], *cloud_in);
```

How do i access the sensor_origin_ and sensor_orientation_ ? I am looking for the exact syntax .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html), they are publicly exposed variables.  The syntax would be

```
cloud_in->sensor_origin_ = cloud_in->sensor_origin_ + noiseVector4f;
```

and

```
cloud_in->sensor_orientation_ = cloud_in->sensor_orientation_ * noiseQuaternionf;
```

Where `noiseVector4f` is a `Eigen::Vector4f` and `noiseQuaternionf` is a `Eigen::Quaternionf`.